# "¿Cómo crear una ventana de ingreso de PIN en una aplicación Gtk# que no se pueda cerrar al hacer clic fuera de ella?"

Tags: c#, .net

Soy nueva usando GTK# en entorno MonoDevelop y no se si esto es posible.
Quiero crear una ventana emergente(ingresar un pin) que aparezca por encima de mi interfaz principal y no se cierre bajo ningún concepto aunque haga click en la interfaz que esta abajo. Para crear la ventana emergente, tengo una clase distinta

He conseguido que la de atras se bloquee usando:

```
mainWindow.Sensitive = false;
```

Y para que la emergente no desaparezca he probado:

```
private void OnFocusOutEvent(object o, FocusOutEventArgs args)
    {
        // Evitar que la ventana pierda el enfoque
        this.GrabFocus();
    }
```

Pero no hay manera